How do you set the account consistency level the CosmosDB emulator in docker?
I'm using the Docker containerized CosmosDB Emulator with a dotnet core test project.
I got an exception because the code was requesting "strong" consistency, which for our real azure environment is fine, but the emulator rejected it with the following
System.ArgumentException
ConsistencyLevel Strong specified in the request is invalid when service is 
configured with consistency level Session.
Ensure the request consistency level is not stronger than the service
consistency level.

   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Handlers.RequestInvokerHandler.ValidateAndSetConsistencyLevelAsync(RequestMessage requestMessage)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Handlers.RequestInvokerHandler.SendAsync(RequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Handlers.RequestInvokerHandler.SendAsync(String resourceUriString, ResourceType resourceType, OperationType operationType, RequestOptions requestOptions, ContainerInternal cosmosContainerCore, FeedRange feedRange, Stream streamPayload, Action`1 requestEnricher, ITrace trace, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.ContainerCore.ProcessItemStreamAsync(Nullable`1 partitionKey, String itemId, Stream streamPayload, OperationType operationType, ItemRequestOptions requestOptions, ITrace trace, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.ContainerCore.ExtractPartitionKeyAndProcessItemStreamAsync[T](Nullable`1 partitionKey, String itemId, T item, OperationType operationType, ItemRequestOptions requestOptions, ITrace trace, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.ContainerCore.CreateItemAsync[T](T item, ITrace trace, Nullable`1 partitionKey, ItemRequestOptions requestOptions, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.ClientContextCore.RunWithDiagnosticsHelperAsync[TResult](String containerName, String databaseName, OperationType operationType, ITrace trace, Func`2 task, Func`2 openTelemetry, String operationName, RequestOptions requestOptions)
   at Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.ClientContextCore.<>c__DisplayClass31_0`1.<<OperationHelperWithRootTraceWithSynchronizationContextAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()
...

The request is using the options when creating an item:
await container.CreateItemAsync
(
    item: item,
    partitionKeyValue,
    new ItemRequestOptions { ConsistencyLevel = ConsistencyLevel.Strong },
    cancellationToken
);


How do you configure the emulator to pretend to be using strong consistency so that it doesn't reject the request?
I've read up on the consistency models, so I get why you can't ask for strong when the cosmos is configured for the weaker "session" consistency. But I can't find any reference for how to make the emulator act like it's in "strong" mode. I don't want to change the code as it's been written to use "strong" presumably for good reason, and weakening the request could break something subtle but important in the system I'm looking at.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/consistency-levels
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/emulator
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/emulator-linux (the one that runs in docker)


Also raised as an issue because I think this might be a missing feature https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-db-emulator-docker/issues/141

Add it via additional args:
  cosmosdb:
    image: mcr.microsoft.com/cosmosdb/linux/azure-cosmos-emulator
    environment:
      AZURE_COSMOS_EMULATOR_ARGS: "/Consistency=Strong"

This is passed through by the start.sh file in the emulator:
docker exec -it devcontainer-cosmosdb-1 /bin/bash

root@a3ea5276c3a3:/usr/local/bin/cosmos/bin#
grep --line-number OTHER_ARGS start.sh 

11:EMULATOR_OTHER_ARGS="${AZURE_COSMOS_EMULATOR_ARGS:-/enablepreview}"
14:     EMULATOR_OTHER_ARGS="$EMULATOR_OTHER_ARGS /EnableMongoDBEndpoint=${AZURE_COSMOS_EMULATOR_ENABLE_MONGODB_ENDPOINT}"
16:     EMULATOR_OTHER_ARGS="$EMULATOR_OTHER_ARGS /nocompute"
70:./cosmosdb-emulator -w $COSMOS_APP_HOME/appdata -- /Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Emulator.exe /enablepreview /disableRIO /minimal $EMULATOR_PARTITION_SETTINGS /disablethrottling $EMULATOR_CERTIFICATE_OPTION /alternativenames=$EMULATOR_IP_ADDRESS,$EMULATOR_OTHER_IP_ADDRESSES /alternativeips=$EMULATOR_IP_ADDRESS,$EMULATOR_OTHER_IP_ADDRESSES /publicipaddressoverride=$EMULATOR_IP_ADDRESS /AllowNetworkAccess /Key=$EMULATOR_KEY $EMULATOR_OTHER_ARGS

